# How to Find the Area of This Composite Figure

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

In my assignment, I have this problem that I must find the **exact** value for:

[image]

I'm not sure, but I think I should first draw another triangle above the 35 cm, making a rectangle. I could find the area of the rectangle (49 * 23). Then, I can do the Pythagorean Theorem for that other triangle (35^2+b^2=49^2 ---> b=sqrt 1176), subtracting the total from the rectangle area. But, to me, this method is not correct because there is a small triangle-shaped space near the 23 cm, so I'm not sure my finding of the area will work.

Step by step, could you explain how you would find the area of this composite?

Comment: Is the left side of the rectangle also 23 cm?

Comment: @AustinWeaver My actual problem does not say, but yes.

Comment: In your picture, the upper one of the three right angles is not actually drawn as a 90 degree angle. If you try to make a drawing where that angle actually is right, then you end up with the weird picture in my answer.. But if we assume not the words but the drawing to be correct, then your method is fine!

Answer (score 4):

Fiddling around with geometry toys, I was able to make this:

[image]

Here, $AC,AD$ and $EF$ are fixed lengths, and angles $A,C$ and $E$ are fixed to be right angles. The lengths of $CF$ and $ED$ are derived by the program, and I guess are not exact.

The only problem I have, is that, when I drag $E$ so the angle becomes right, and $F$ and $D$ are at the same height, I get this:

[image]

So I am not so sure if the exercise is completely sensible.

Comment: Thank you for your representation, @Insert_name_here. But CF=AD, so CF=23 in my problem.

Comment: I think that is not possible. Either I made a mistake in my construction of the figure, or we need to drop e.g. that angle $E$ needs be right.

Comment: Since $ED$ is not fixed, why can't you drop $F$ down a little ways and still maintain the right angle? Why do you think the figure is fixed?

Comment: Oh right, the figure is not fixed! And the area isn't either!

Comment: My turn to ask you: why is it clear that the area isn't fixed? :)

Comment: Because I constructed the figure geometrically, in a program that can measure the area ;)

Comment: I guess that's better than my "clearly" handwave...

Comment: `So I am not so sure if the exercise is completely sensible.` +1 for catching that. Point $E$ drops below $CA\,$ in that case, indeed, because $35 \cdot \sqrt{49^2 - 35^2} / 49 \simeq 24.5 \gt 23\,$.

Answer (score 3):

If the length of the left-hand vertical line is also 23 cm, your answer is correct, since the line across the top completes a rectangle.

Otherwise, this is not a well-posed question. For example, imagine the left-hand vertical line being stretchable, and the two diagonal lines being glued together in a right angle. As the left-hand line stretches, you can maintain the right angle (possibly by changing the length of the unlabeled diagonal line), and the area clearly changes.

Comment: Yeah? Does the area _clearly_ change, when you don't assume the left-hand vertical is 23 cm?

Comment: Well, I think it does, at least for some positions of the upper left-hand point. For example, move the left-hand point up to the highest possible point so that you can maintain a $90^{\circ}$ angle. Isn't it clear then? But yes, I agree, perhaps "clearly" was a bit overexuberant and it requires a bit of proof.